# Boto3 library vs REST to invoke AWS lambda from python services

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3

Are there reasons I shouldn't be using `boto3` library in python to invoke my AWS Lambda and use REST instead?

Some background:
I am evaluating lambdas for certain workflows triggered from my main webserver.
The general setup I have is

- main `Django` app running in a k8s cluster with
- a few microservices communicating with main webserver via `gRPC`
- lambdas would live in a VPC (same as the above services and webserver)

I'm looking to introduce lambdas into the stack.
It seems like I could use `boto3` library to invoke my lambdas from my python services (either the main webserver app or the microservices).
Are there any reasons `boto3` would be a bad idea?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to **directly invoke** lambda is through Lambda Service. For that you have to use AWS CLI, SDK (e.g. boto3) or AWS Console. This requires to have valid IAM credentials with permissions for lambda invocation.

The **indirect** way of invoking lambda is through API Gateway with lambda proxy integration. This allows invoking lambda without IAM credentails, and is mostly useful for allow public access, e.g. in web browser.

Since you are writing that you want to invoke lambda from your backend server or conatiner:

> I could use boto3 library to invoke my lambdas from my python services

using `boto3` would be recommended way. The permissions for lambda invocation should be configured in  **instance or task roles**.

Comment: Thank you! That's a great explanation to what I was looking for.

Comment: Do you know what protocol is boto3 using to invoke lambdas ?

Comment: @HIT_girl Hi. It uses [lambda service rest api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Reference.html).